# https only in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, https, maven-gae-plugin

I am on a google app engine project now. In my application I have to allow only https protocol. And I have to restrict other protocols. It should allow https only. I have added the below code in web.xml.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But after deploying it works on both the protocols(http and https). How to restrict http?

Comment: Are you testing the same version of the app you deployed to?  Have you tried removing the "<web-resource-name>"?

Comment: I am testing the same version I deployed. I have not tested by removing the web resource name.Let me try that now.Thanks.

Answer (score 68):

It is possible to configure the individual handlers to require HTTPS in the app.yaml file in the WEB-INF folder as described here: [Java Application Configuration Using app.yaml - Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml.html#Secure_URLs).

You just have to add these two words to your `app.yaml` file under the appropriate `url` entry:
`secure: always`

For example:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
  secure: always
```

Then if a user tries to access the URL with HTTP she will be automatically redirected to HTTPS. Pretty cool.

Comment: It appears that SSL support for custom domains have been added for GAE now. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl?hl=fr Thanks for the:
secure: always part

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Removed that paragraph (as strike-through is not available here).

Comment: can I run an App on GAE without SSL?

Comment: Yes. That’s the default.

Comment: How can I do this with nodejs? The `url` entry doesn't seem available in app.yaml.

Comment: Would love to know how to do this using Ruby on Rails

Comment: in documentation you need to use: `- url: ./*`. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/application-security

Answer (score 16):

If you want to stick with "web.xml" rather than using the "app.yaml" option (which will overwrite your web.xml & appengine-web.xml files at deploy time), you can add in:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>everything</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication

Answer (score 4):

Are you using your own domain? At present, GAE supports SSL for *.appspot.com domains [only](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2008/10/announcing-https-support-for-appspotcom.html). They have been [promising](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) SSL support for non-appspot domains for some time now and we're all waiting for news on that front.

Comment: SSL for a custom domain is supported now https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

This is for future folks !!!

1. **In java** adding the code below in my `web.xml` file worked for me

   ```
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>HTTPS redirect</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
   ```
2. For other project add `secure: always` under all urls in `app.yaml` file

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.xml file

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```