# Google Cloud Platform, Golang Flexible Environment HTTPS only for custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, go, https, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed my application without hassle just by running `gcloud app deploy` command on GCP. Which takes the flexible environment as default. Yesterday I made the necessary customizations to have a custom domain for this app with ssl. Currently it works when I go to any of the following, `http://example.com`, `https://example.com` but I also want to force people to use https. Currently the http requests work as they are, I want them to be directed to https. I want to direct any user to `https://example.com` when they try to go to the website with http or without anything at all like `example.com`. How can this be achieved?

Here's my `app.yaml`:

```
api_version: go1
env: flex
runtime: go
```

I already tried to use `handlers and secure` attributes but it seems they are not valid for flexible environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367974/https-only-in-google-app-engine]

Comment: @PrateekGupta You should first read the question before reaching this kind of decision. The question you posted does not involve flexible environment. Also I already mentioned that the solution offered there does not work because of the flexible environment case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, flexible environment does not support HTTPS only directing by using `app.yaml`. However, this can be achieved in the server code by using a function like this,

```
func directToHttps(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
    if r.URL.Scheme == "https" || strings.HasPrefix(r.Proto, "HTTPS") || r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-Proto") == "https" {
        next(w, r)
    } else {
        target := "https://" + r.Host + r.URL.Path

        http.Redirect(w, r, target,
            http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    }
}
```

I wrapped this function to my handlers with `negroni`.

Working example can be found here: https://github.com/malisit/munhasir

Comment: should the `next(w, r)` after the else be removed?

Comment: It actually make sense, thank you for correcting. Please feel free to edit!